# Apache POI: Create a cell with type number, but to be empty

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to create an excel document. What I need is to have a column with type number. The problem, which I have is that not every cell in this column has a value( some of them should be empty).
I have one method, which I call in order to create the cells. I have problem  when from the methods parameters get "null", because the setCellValue(double value) can't take null as parameter. This is why I decided to check if it is null to put the cell type: empty.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa74J.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lk4Mf.png)

At the end what worked for me is: I just put something to the cell if the value is not null. This worked for me.

```
private void createCell(String cellStyle, String cellValue){
    cell = row.createCell(cellNumber++);
    cell.setCellStyle(styles.get(cellStyle));

    if (cellStyle.equals("numberWithDelimiters")) {
        if(cellValue!=null){
            cell.setCellValue(Integer.parseInt(cellValue));
        }

    }else if(cellStyle.equals("date")){
        Date date=new Date(Long.parseLong(cellValue));
        date.setHours(0);
        cell.setCellValue(date);
    }else{
    cell.setCellValue(cellValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at solution

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation

```
 XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(1);
 cell.setCellStyle(Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
 cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC );
```

Comment: Hello :) I already tried this. The cell after this is empty, but the type of the cell is transformed to "General" and I want to be the same as the other filled in cells "number".  For example if you make a cell with type number, but don't type anything it will be still "number" and for me it is shown as "General"

Comment: please see the sceenshots

Comment: @Silvia Petrova  Check now

Comment: I'm not able to set the style like this. It expects CellStyle, not int. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

*@Mohit sharma* answer is deprecated, for new POI API use:

```
cell.setCellType(CellType.BLANK);
```